# Beautiful Soup processing

Tags: python, sorting, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap the name and ratings of different travel agents from http://www.indiacom.com/yellow-pages/travel-agencies-and-services/
Here is my code

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    url="http://www.indiacom.com/yellow-pages/travel-agencies-and-services/"
    r=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    links=soup.find_all("a")
    #for link in links:
     #   if"http" in link.get("href"):
      #      print("<a href='%s'>%s</a>"%(link.get("href"),link.text))
    L=[]
    g_data=soup.find_all("div",{"class": "Info_listing"})
    for item in g_data:
        L.append(item.contents[3].text)
       # L.append(item.text)
    for index in L:
        print(index)
    #print(L[2])
```

I am saving names and ratings in a list.Now I want to sort on the basis of ratings. How do i do that because if someone is rated their rating is displayed but if someone is not rated it comes "Be the first to rate" So how do I sort on the basis of rating

Comment: how does the list look like?

Comment: When I print the list it looks like this http://i.imgur.com/0ecAvrc.png  first name comes then rating comes with a lot of space in between

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over listings, construct a list of tuples containing listing names and ratings. The use `sorted()` to sort by rating value. Treat `Be The First To Rate` as a 0 rating:

```
from operator import itemgetter

listings = []
for item in soup.select("div.Details_listing"):
    name = item.a.text
    rating = item.find('div', id='total_ratings_details').text
    rating = 0 if rating.startswith('Be The First To Rate') else float(rating.split(' ')[0])

    listings.append((name, rating))

print sorted(listings, key=itemgetter(1))
```

Prints:

```
[
    (u'Jasvinder Tours And Travels', 0),
    ...
    (u'The Royal Tours & Travels', 2.9), 
    (u'Preeti Travels & Transport', 4.4)
]
```

Comment: What if I want to do the same thing for all the pages?Do I have to pass url every time for page1,page2,page3 or is there some kind of command to scrap?